# How to add production and development server_api_url in jhipster?

Tags: angular, jhipster, angular-fullstack, jhipster-gateway

I have created angular + spring boot application using jhipster. Now during development i have used localhost:8080 for calling apis. But in production i need to update server_api_url to something http://mysever:8080. How to config such thing in jhipster?

Comment: Why do you need to set a full URL with protocol and domain name? If your backend serves your frontend bundle you can use only /api.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou , Actually i deployed the bundle application in rdp server in which my application runs in port 9000 of rdp server. I need to use http://serverip:9000 in production testing.

Comment: What do you mean by RDP, remote desktop protocol? There must be something clever I don't understand.  If same server/port serves both js bundle and api, you need full URL to load your frontend in browser but your frontend code just needs /api to access API.

Comment: @i-vignesh-david
Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, in jhipster i added the url for prod in webpack.prod.js under the webpack folder